# Obtaining Historic Values from SQL

Tags: sql

I have a longitudinal table populated with, among other things, dates and balances.  I need to extract 6 variables containing the balances for each of the last 6 months.  This seems as though it should be incredibly easy to do, but I have had no luck so far using case or if statements within select.

My entire program loops through my data by date.

With a table that looks something like this:

```
col1    |col2   |account    |date   |balance    |col3   |col4
--------------------------------------------------------------
        |       |123456     |Jul-16 |1200       |       |
        |       |123456     |Jun-16 |1100       |       |
        |       |123456     |May-16 |1000       |       |
        |       |123456     |Apr-16 |900        |       |
        |       |123456     |Mar-16 |800        |       |
        |       |123456     |Feb-16 |700        |       |
        |       |123456     |Jan-16 |600        |       |
        |       |123456     |Dec-15 |500        |       |
        |       |123456     |Nov-15 |400        |       |
        |       |123456     |Oct-15 |300        |       |
        |       |123456     |Sep-15 |200        |       |
        |       |123456     |Aug-15 |100        |       |
        |       |234567     |Jul-16 |-500       |       |
        |       |234567     |Jun-16 |-400       |       |
        |       |234567     |May-16 |-600       |       |
        |       |234567     |Apr-16 |-500       |       |
        |       |234567     |Mar-16 |-200       |       |
        |       |234567     |Feb-16 |-400       |       |
        |       |345678     |Jul-16 |100        |       |
        |       |345678     |Jun-16 |200        |       |
        |       |345678     |May-16 |300        |       |
        |       |345678     |Apr-16 |400        |       |
        |       |345678     |Mar-16 |500        |       |
```

I would require variables b1-b6 giving me the balance for each account over the last 6 months.

Comment: Please post table definition, data and expected results. Also RDBMS vendor and version.

Comment: It would be easier to get help if you show the `schema outline` of your tables and an example of the output you want.

Comment: I've tried using case statements and if loops.  The data is sensitive, so I would need to doctor it before posting a sample.  I'll see if I can come up with a fake example table, but working flat out at the moment.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: you don't need a case or if statement, you need to group by the year(datefld) and month(datefld).  Or, if you don't want aggregate results and want all the detail, limit by datefld in your WHERE clause.

Comment: I wonder how you are going to extract a variable from an SQL query.

Comment: Search for "Top N per group"

Comment: No, I need to generate 6 new variables - something along the lines of PROC TRANSPOSE in SAS...

Answer (score 1):

Its difficult to tell if this is what exactly you are looking for but if you are looking for the balance accumulated for each account over 6 months, the below may help.

```
   SELECT  account, SUM(balance)
    FROM    Table_1 
    WHERE   date >= '2013-02-02' AND
            date <= '2013-08-02'
GROUP BY account
```

The 'GROUP BY' function will summarize the aggregated variable or `SUM(balance)` by each 'account' and the where clause will return the aggregated value for the date range. You could add the other variables into the select statement and the 'GROUP BY'.

Answer (score 1):

Although this is basically a top N per group problem it looks like you consistently have data every month which should make it easier to handle.

```
select t.*
from
    <T> t inner join
    (select account, max(date) as max_date from <T> group by account) m
        on m.account = t.account and t.date > max_date - 6 months /* pseudo-code */
```

You have to compute the six-month look-back according to your business rules. There may also be some small complications with dates near the end of the month (February in particular.) This is just a rough template of one approach that will *probably* work on your platform. And depending on assumptions you can make there are possibilities for optimizing this.